# value not being recorded in <input>?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check if two input boxes have the same value in them but the problem is that it always shows them with the same value. I think the values aren't being stored in value??

```
<div class="errorbox-good">
        <div>
            <div class="form-entry">
                <label>
                    <div> First Name
                        <span class="ss-required-asterisk">*</span>
                    </div>
                </label>
                    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" required> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 

<div class="errorbox-good">
        <div>
            <div class="form-entry">
                <label>
                    <div> Last Name
                        <span class="ss-required-asterisk">*</span>
                    </div>
                </label>
                    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" required> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('input').blur(function () {
    if ($('#fname').attr('value') == $('#lname').attr('value')) {
        alert('Same Value');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
 });
});
```

When I try and alert the `$('#fname').attr('value')` it says undefined. Are the values not being recorded correctly or is it something else?

Here is the jsfiddle. It works, but not when I run the same code on my local machine.
http://jsfiddle.net/g2kBm/56/

Comment: your code is working its alerting when both has same value.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.val()` jQuery method.

> **Description:** Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements.

```
$("#fname").val();
```

#### [Read More](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
if ($('#fname').val() == $('#lname').val()) {
    alert('Same Value');
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

instead, the attr() is not used to get the value of the input. That's used to add an attribute to the input. That's also the reason you are getting an 'undefined' message.

Answer (score 0):

May be just modify this small part, may this will help you.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('input').blur(function () {
    if ($('#fname').val() == $('#lname').val()) {
        alert('Same Value');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined `$('#fname').attr('value')` and it says undefined. if you want to use **value attribute** you must declare it first. but you not declared and try to get value of input.

Using `jquery` if you want to check value , you can use `val()`.

```
if ($('#fname').val() == $('#lname').val()) {
    alert('Same Value');
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```